# Prove that the Eigenvalues of this Matrix are in [0,1 ]

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Let $E,F \subset \mathbb{R^n}$

Note that $< . >$ defines the Inner product on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Let $(e_1,....,e_k)$ and $(f_1,.....f_l$) be Orthonormal bases of E and F respectively.

Consider the Matrix $A=(<e_i,f_j>)$ of size $k*l$

Let $\lambda_i$ be an Eigenvalue of  $A^T A$

Prove that $\lambda_i \in [0, 1] \; \; \forall i$ and that they do not depend on the choice of bases of $E$ and $F$

I tryed experimenting on a small dimension matrix but I'm not able to figure it out. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you mean $A_{i,j} ~~=~~ <e_i,~f_j>$ ?

Comment: @DanielV yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is any inner product space and $W$ is a subspace, then there is a natural orthogonal projection map $P_W:V \to W$. These projections have several important properties. Among these we can show that $P_W$ has operator norm equal to $1$ and is positive-semidefinite.
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthogonal_complements_and_projections)

We will consider the maps $P_E: \mathbb{R}^n \to E$ and $P_F: \mathbb{R}^n \to F$, and in particular we will consider the restrictions of these maps to appropriate subspaces.

Specifically, notice that $A^t$ is the matrix for $P_F|_E:E \to F$ with respect to the bases $(e_1,\dots,e_k)$ and $(f_1,\dots,f_l)$. Also notice that $A$ is the matrix for $P_E|_F:F \to E$ with respect to the bases $(f_1,\dots,f_l)$ and $(e_1,\dots,e_k)$. This can be easily computed using the definition of the matrix for a linear map and the properties of these projections.

It follows that $A^tA$ is the matrix for the map $P=P_F \circ P_E: F \to F$ with respect to the basis $(f_1, \dots, f_l)$. Since $P_E$ and $P_F$ have operator norm equal to $1$, it follows that $P$ has operator norm less than or equal to 1. Thus, all eigenvalues have absolute value less than or equal to $1$. But $P$ is also a positive semidefinite operator on $F$ (because for any $v \in F$, we have that $\langle Pv,v \rangle = \langle P_Ev, P_Fv \rangle = \langle P_Ev, v \rangle = ||P_Ev||^2\geq 0$), and thus the eigenvalues of $P$ must be non-negative. Then it immediately follows that the eigenvalues of $P$ (and thus $A^tA$) must be in $[0,1]$.

These eigenvalues only depend on the maps $P_E$ and $P_F$. In other words these eigenvalues only depend on the subspaces $E$ and $F$, and not the choices of bases. Also notice that this could have been done in any inner product space. Nothing special about $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

Write $M_{E}$ as the matrix with the columns $e_j$ and $M_{F}$ as the matrix with the columns $f_j$, then notice that $A = M_E^T M_F$. Notice we are searching for $\left\|A \right\| = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA)}$ and trying to show that it is less than $1$. 
Now $\left\|A\right\| \leq \left\|M_E \right\| \left\|M_F\right\|$ and since $M^T_E M_E = I_k$, $M^T_F M_F = I_l$ we have $\left\|M_E \right\| =  1 , \left\|M_F \right\| = 1$ and finally yield $\left\|A\right\| \leq 1 $.

Comment: All *nonzero* eigenvalues are 1.

Comment: Yes. missed that detail.

Comment: Must say, it's been a while since I saw the SVD used in an answer. Nice job !

Comment: How does this show that the eigenvalues don't depend on the choice of bases? We know that the eigenvalues will always be 0 or 1, but it is possible that different choices of bases give different numbers of 0's and 1's, right?

Comment: @Shalop No, the number of 1s in the spectrum is the smaller of the dimension of $ E$ and that of $ F $.

Comment: I'm not convinced that all eigenvalues must be $0$ or $1$. Consider this two-dimensional example. Let $E$ be the 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ spanned by $(1,1)$. Let $F$ be the subspace spanned by $(1,0)$. Let $e_1=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, and let $f_1=(1,0)$. Then $A$ is the $1 \times 1$ matrix whose only entry is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thus $A^tA=[\frac{1}{2}]$, which has eigenvalue $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Another counterexample is provided in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $E$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $e_1=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$,and $F$ is the two-dimensional subspace whose orthonormal basis is $f_1=(1,0,0)$ and $f_2=(0,1,0)$. In this case $A^tA$ will have $\frac{2}{3}$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: You are right, I was not careful with the previous proof. I mixed up the order of the transposes necessary for the presented decomposition. This should work now :).

Comment: This shows that the eigenvalues are less than 1, but why does it imply that the spectrum of eigenvalues is independent of the choice of bases for $E$ and $F$?